# Debug Angular app in vscode works, but requires me to hit a breakpoint in browser first?

Tags: angular, docker, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am having trouble debugging my angular app. The app itself runs inside a docker image. I created a mount for the source files, so that I can rely on ng recompiling changes will serving. All works well, but debugging is somewhat unreliable.

When I put a breakpoint in my source (app init e.g.) and I launch firefox through vscode using

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch firefox",
            "type": "firefox",
            "profileDir": "/home/bp/snap/firefox/common/.cache/mozilla/firefox/c90bexwg.default-release",
            "keepProfileChanges": true,
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
            "tmpDir": "./webapp/.firefox-temp",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "url": "webpack:///src",
                    "path": "${workspaceFolder}/webapp/src"
                },
                {
                    "url": "webpack:///node_modules",
                    "path": "${workspaceFolder}/webapp/node_modules"
                },
                {
                    "url": "webpack:///webpack",
                    "path": "${workspaceFolder}/webapp/webpack"
                }
            ]
        },
```

the breakpoint will not hit. When I refresh the page a couple of times, same story, the breakpoint won't hit.

But, when I also open the debugger in the browser (f12 for firefox) and add a breakpoint in the same file, that breakpoint will hit. And magically, after having hit a breakpoint in firefox browser, my breakpoints in vscode are also working fine.

I tried to google for this, but came up kind of empty.

Does anybody recognize this behavior and have a clue what is causing this, and if its fixable?

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to not develop your app with Docker and have this Docker step once you build the app for production. Develop directly on your computer, use `ng serve --o` and add breakpoints on your browser.

Comment: ah thx, that makes sense too. I was so "burned" on getting it to work with all in docker everywhere, but maybe for the angular app it doesn't make much sense. I'll take this in consideration if nothing else comes by :)